# Boolean function proving contradiction ,tautology or neither

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether $((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow r)\Leftrightarrow (p \Rightarrow(q \Rightarrow r))$ is a tautology, a contradiction, or neither.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\underline{p}&\underline{q}&\underline{r}& \underline{((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow r)\Leftrightarrow (p \Rightarrow(q \Rightarrow r))}\\
0&0&0&               0\\
0&0&1&               1\\
0&1&0&               0\\
0&1&1&               1\\
1&0&0&               1\\
1&0&1&               1\\
1&1&0&               1\\
1&1&1&               1\\
\end{array}$$

So it is neither contradiction or tautology since the last column has both 1 and 0 values.
Is this correct?
I need your feedback please
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you computed the right values, you are correct. It would be neither a tautology (always true) nor a contradiction (never true).